# F# Type Provider for postgresql raw queries compatible with .NET6+?

Tags: f#, .net-6.0, type-providers

I realize there's similar questions about this on SO however a lot of them are over 5 years old, and the projects they're referring to have since gone stale. For instance [this](https://github.com/fsprojects/Rezoom.SQL) project seems exactly what I'm looking for, but it's no longer maintained.

I'm wondering if there's an actively maintained F# type provider for postgresql raw sql queries? Something like dapper/npgsql but with type provider support (ie: realtime intellisense type checking against the db schema, etc)?

From my research [SQL Provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/) seems to be actively maintained and supports postgresql, however it looks to be for ORM, and not raw SQL queries.

I'd go ahead and help maintain an outdated project but I'm just learning F# and following a book ("Get Programming with F#") that has just introduced me to type providers. The examples in the book are useful for the CSV & HTML providers however unfortunately the book is outdated with the SQL type providers shown, thus I'm in the process of still trying to actually understand how they work.

So in essence my question is, is there a type provider for F# raw sql postgresql queries compatible with .NET6+?

Answer (score 1):

We have a "working" fork of Rezoom.SQL here: https://github.com/valora-digital/Rezoom.SQL

There's no NuGet package for it, but you can include it directly in your .Net6 solution and reference it, and it will work as it should. We haven't updated it beyond that yet. My long term plan with it is to rename the entire project, and create a new NuGet for it as we can't get ahold of the original maintainer to get write access to the existing NuGet.

Comment: this looks like a great project! And good to see it supports SQL Server, postgresql, sqlite, the three dbs I mostly am interested in. Hope you manage to get a Nuget package out there